# How can I pass this model data down to a child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a task manager (to-do list) app I'm creating. I'm fairly new to Angular. I'm not sure how I should properly initialize this model in the parent in order to properly pass it down to a child component.

I have the list property optional in the below model since there will be a moment when the list is first created where it will only have a title and no list created yet.

Model...

```
export class List {
    constructor(public title: string, 
                public list?: [{ task: string, completed: boolean }], 
                public color?: string) {}
}
```

The below component should be able to pass new lists that don't have a list property created yet and* previously created lists that have the property. It has a service injected where a list was created. It only starts out with a name, then this component subscribes to a field that shows the current active list for viewing and assigns it to "currentList" on ngOnInit.

List.ts... (parent component)

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  listSubscription: Subscription;
  currentList: List;

  constructor(private listService: ListService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listSubscription = this.listService.showCurrentList.subscribe(
      list => {
        this.currentList = list;
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.listSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

HTML...

```
<app-view-list 
    [list]="currentList">
</app-view-list>
```

View-List.ts... (child component)

```
export class ViewListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() list: List;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

Any tips or direction how to go about this would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: After assign the value to currentList, did you check the value exist in that list?

Comment: looks right did you check to make sure the subscription is sending the data to currentList

Comment: Ahh, I was able to get it working by initializing the parent as...

`currentList: List = { title: '', list: [{ task: '', completed: false }] };`

But I just wasn't sure if it was best practice to initialize it with empty strings, but I suppose that won't hurt if those properties will just be assigned each time the component pulls data from the service.